# Quorum PrivateFor Not Working in Web3 - From Account Address to Smart Contract Address

Tags: contract-invocation, quorum

I am using Web3 to send a transaction to a smart contract address. The public transactions are working OK. However, when I use the PrivateFor parameter in the web3 call, the transaction is still sent to the nodes but not working correctly.

Is this a configuration issue or web3 does not support for PrivateFor transaction as yet?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the "not working correctly" part? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not explaining all the details.

**Suggestion: **

- Make sure you are using web3-quorum package from below link:

[quorum-web3 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-quorum)

Comment: I was using the latest web3 beta. quorum-web3 is abit behind. I have a huge smart contract that I am unable to deploy to the blockchain. Other than changing the maxCodeSize, and recompiling the code, do you know how to work around that?

Comment: Web3 beta and web3-quorum serves different purpose, you can't just use web3 beta for quorum development, you have to use the web3-quorum for that. web3 beta is for ethereum, it doesn't include all the functionality of web3-quorum.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [quorum.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quorum-js) which is the official release of web3.js for quorum. You can read it here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/604